# Swift: Streaming video file from pc

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I would like to play a video file which is on my local PC (path: "http://192.168.1.5:9000/assets/uploadedFiles/4.mp4"). My iPhone and my PC are both in the same network. My following code works fine if I play videos on my iPhone. Otherwise it displays only a black screen.

```
    self.objMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url!)
    self.objMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
    self.objMoviePlayerController.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds
    self.objMoviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
    self.objMoviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    self.objMoviePlayerController.contentURL = url!
    self.objMoviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = true

    self.videoView.addSubview(self.objMoviePlayerController.view)

    self.objMoviePlayerController.prepareToPlay()
    self.objMoviePlayerController.play()
```

I don't want to download the video file to my iPhone. Is there a way to stream the video file from my PC? Thanks